# Adobe illustrator: basic editing questions (break apart)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have some experience with Flash/Gimp/Photoshop, but now I have to edit an FXG file (an asset for a Flex app) in Adobe Illustrator and can't do even the two basic things, shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

1. I need to double the size of the clubs symbol in the middle while maintaining its central alignment
2. I need to change the indices in the corners (by different text)

but I can't even select the clubs symbol or the indices! Whenever I click and drag - I select and move everything. Do I need to break apart like in Flash editor? Can't find it in the Adobe Illustrator menu.

**UPDATE:**

Thank you Scott, this has worked after the Ungroup.

I wonder though, why can't I select anything in the layers window (I realized after some time that there are indeed several layers already). I click on a layer, but nothing is selected.

I'm asking, because I want to place the new text symmetrically.

[image]

Comment: Click on the small circle on the right. When selected a small blue square will appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select the club symbol with the Direct Selection Tool (the white arrow -- click, don't drag). Then double-click the Scale Tool in the Toolbar and enter your desired percentage for increase.
2. You'll need to delete the "A" and reset a new character. That type has been converted to outlines and is no longer editable text.

As for the "break apart"... There is Object > Ungroup after you've selected the objects.

### Layers Question

Illustrator layers don't work like Photoshop layers. Selecting and highlighting layers in Illustrator lets you move, copy, or delete the actual layer in the Layers Panel. It does not select the objects on any particular layer.

If you want to select the objects on a layer, click the circle to the right of the layer's name. You'll see a small square highlight appear. That will indicate objects on that layer are selected.

The layer functionality difference is basically the difference between an object-oriented app like Illustrator and a raster app like Photoshop.

Comment: thank you! Do you have any advice, on how to place my new indices (I want to replace the both "A" letters by my own font) in a *symmetrical* way?

Comment: I've added to my answer to cover the layers question. You should post the symmetrical edit as a new question. IT can be done. But I dont' want to load one answer with multiple questions. It makes it hard for other users to find solutions.

Comment: Thank you, I've posted the new question at http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6957/adobe-illustrator-symmetrical-editing-of-card-indices-a-k-q-j-etc

Answer (score 0):

With compound paths in Illustrator, you often need to right-click and choose *Release Compound Path* (as well as ungroup).

Can also be found under *Object > Compound Path > Release*.